# Open Client Local files in chrome from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, google-chrome-extension, local-files

In upgrading our LOB app to html5 we've got to handle the legacy issue of local linked documents in our application.

Scenario is in our old winforms app the user could attach a document to an entity as a link i.e. C:\Rules.txt . When they print out reports the application would load these documents from the users computer and print them with the report.

Now rolling this into an asp.net mvc web application has presented some difficulty. I've been able to handle it using the following for internet explorer.

```
   ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

This works fine as long as they allow all the permissions for activeX to run which is fine, if they want locally linked docs then this is something they have to do.

That's IE sorted. We just need to find something that will accomplish this for Google Chrome (these 2 browsers cover > 90% of user base so im not phased about the others i.e. safari, firefox).

Does anyone know of anything we can use for google chrome to load a file located on the users machine (that is not accessible directly from the web server) using javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can't use let the users select the files themselves using an `<input type="file" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for the reply. No it's all going to be dynamically loaded at runtime under the hood since the user has already linked the docs into the system